# Issue with MySQL query cache

Tags: mysql, query-cache

I ran the following sql against MySQL:

```
SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Qcache%';
```

Here is what I got:

```
Qcache_free_blocks  0
Qcache_free_memory  0
Qcache_hits 0
Qcache_inserts  0
Qcache_lowmem_prunes    0
Qcache_not_cached   0
Qcache_queries_in_cache 0
Qcache_total_blocks 0
```

I don't understand why I get this because I did double-check that the query cache is properlty enabled as follows:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'have_query_cache';

Variable_name   Value
have_query_cache    YES
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you read [the MySQL Query Cache Configuration page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-cache-configuration.html)?

E.g.

> When using a standard MySQL binary, this value is always YES, even if query caching is disabled.

or

> To set the size of the query cache, set the query_cache_size system variable. Setting it to 0 disables the query cache. The default size is 0, so the query cache is disabled by default. To reduce overhead significantly, also start the server with query_cache_type=0 if you will not be using the query cache.